# Mkdir duplication in elfinder

Tags: javascript, elfinder

Whenever I try to create new folder with Elfinder in php codeigniter 3 as soon i enter click whenever giving file name it create folder two times

1. It creates folder
2. **and save it two times(main issue)**
3. and show error file already existed

> [
> "errMkdir",
> "NewFolder 3",
> "errExists",
> "NewFolder 3"
> ]
> {
> "error": [
> "errMkdir",
> "NewFolder 2"
> ],
> "debug": {
> "connector": "php",
> "phpver": "7.4.21",
> "time": 0.5570311546325684,
> "memory": "6187Kb / 2314Kb / 512M",
> "upload": "",
> "volumes": [
> {
> "id": "l1_",
> "name": "localfilesystem",
> "mimeDetect": "finfo",
> "imgLib": "gd"
> },
> {
> "id": "t1_",
> "name": "trash",
> "mimeDetect": "finfo",
> "imgLib": "gd"
> }
> ],
> "mountErrors": [],
> "backendErrors": [
> "WARNING: mkdir(): File exists in elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem.class.php line 921."
> ]
> }
> }

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Most likely the browser trigger the click event twice